# JavaScript - ] is removed from the first element after the deletion of another element from an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi I have an Array which I would like to remove an element from.

After the deletion of the element from the array, it is saved to localStorage.
However, after loaded from storage it shows that the first element is missing ].

This is the code which I am using to perform the deletion:

```
var dataSet =  (localStorage.getItem('expenditureListFromStorage'));
console.log(dataSet);
//var dataSet = "[" + dataSet + "]";
var dataSet = "[" + dataSet + "]";
console.log("Before parsing" + dataSet);
console.log(dataSet);
var dataSet = JSON.parse(dataSet);
//dataSet.push(dataSet.splice(dataSet.indexOf(selectedExpenditure), 1)[0]);
dataSet.unshift(dataSet.splice(dataSet.indexOf(selectedExpenditure), 1)[0]);
//dataSet.unshift(selectedExpenditure);
console.log("Before Deletion" + dataSet);
dataSet.shift();
//dataSet.pop(dataSet.indexOf(selectedExpenditure), 1);
//dataSet.splice(dataSet.indexOf(selectedExpenditure), 1);
console.log("After Deletion" + dataSet);
localStorage.setItem('expenditureListFromStorage', dataSet);
```

This is the code which I am using when saving the first element to the array:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('expenditureListFromStorage') === null)
    {
        var newExpenditure = [];
        newExpenditure.push([tempExpenditureName, tempExpenditureCategory, tempExpenditureDescription, tempExpenditureOccurrence, tempExpenditurePrice, tempExpenditureDate]);
        newExpenditure = "[" + newExpenditure + "]";
        localStorage.setItem('expenditureListFromStorage', newExpenditure);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('expenditureListFromStorage'));
    }
```

This is the code I am using to add subsequent elements (this piece of code is placed just after the code which saves the first element of an array):

```
else
    {
        var newExpenditure = [];
        newExpenditure.push([tempExpenditureName, tempExpenditureCategory, tempExpenditureDescription, tempExpenditureOccurrence, tempExpenditurePrice, tempExpenditureDate]);
        newExpenditure = "[" + newExpenditure + "]";
        console.log("New Expenditure from Form = " + newExpenditure);
        var expenditureArrayList =  (localStorage.getItem('expenditureListFromStorage'));
        console.log("expenditureArrayList from Storage before parsing" + expenditureArrayList);
        expenditureArrayList = expenditureArrayList + "," + newExpenditure;
        console.log("expenditureArrayList from Storage after parsing" + expenditureArrayList);
        localStorage.setItem('expenditureListFromStorage', (expenditureArrayList));
        console.log(expenditureArrayList);
    }
```

If I do not save these elements this way, I cannot retrieve the array again after loading from localStorage.

I am trying to work with an array in this format
[["Array1Value1", "Array1Value2", "Array1Value3"],["Array2Value1","Array2Value2","Array2Value3"]]

This array would then be retrieved from localStorage and displayed as an HTML table using the dataTables plugin. However the problem is that when I am deleting an element and saving the array without this array, something is breaking the array and its first element.

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: `newExpenditure = "[" + newExpenditure + "]";` please use `JSON.stringify` to turn an array into proper JSON. I'm surprised what you have here works at all after retrieval - converting the array into *string* (implicit when concatenating) will not produce valid JSON and is very likely to produce a value that cannot even be parsed correctly.

Comment: The thing is that it can be parsed correctly without issues.
However, when element is removed from the array it can no longer be parsed after retrieved from localStorage. I tried using Stringify, but parsing could not work after retrieved from localStorage. That's why I am adding [] and , manually when added new elements to the array.

Comment: "*without issues*" I disagree - you are still manually manipulating the string to make it fit for parsing. You shouldn't need to do that and it's definitely an issue.

Comment: -VLAZ, I agree, but as I stated in my previous comment, I could not parse to Array again after retrieving from localStorage, when I used stringify, hence the reason why I am handling the element addition to array manually. This took me almost 2 days to sort it out and have the array parsed properly once retrieved from storage.

Comment: Are you running [JSON.parse(array)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) after retrieving it from local storage?

Comment: Yes, before it is rendered in the html table. The array is parseable before an element array deletion is performed. After the element deletion, the array is saved back to localstorage, however the same code which loads the array from storage, parses it and renders it in the html table, is not able to parse the data retrieved from the storage.